# How to cache API calls via Varnish?

Tags: caching, varnish

My goal is to cache RESTful API calls via Varnish. AS I was reading on stackoverflow and other resources, Varnish can not cache post requests. This is exactly what I am experiencing. Therefore I moved to get with ?id=30 but then I realized that those also do not get cached because of the question mark.

So the question is, how o cache API-Calls over Varnish?

Here are two example calls to my API, secured by Oauth2 with 2 parameters pased by post:

```
curl --insecure -s -k https://test-api/v1/test -d 'access_token=72f50e68a0aed7921c6cb058de8e7e6ed4ebd692&clid=585970' -D- -o/dev/null
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 29 Aug 2015 13:02:36 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.31 (Unix) PHP/5.6.11
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.11
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 2121
Content-Type: application/json
X-Varnish: 6558010
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Set-Cookie: SERVERID=S3; path=/

curl --insecure -s -k https://test-api/v1/test -d 'access_token=72f50e68a0aed7921c6cb058de8e7e6ed4ebd692&clid=585970' -D- -o/dev/null
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 29 Aug 2015 13:02:56 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.31 (Unix) PHP/5.6.11
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.11
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 2121
Content-Type: application/json
X-Varnish: 12814168
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Set-Cookie: SERVERID=S2; path=/
```

Is it possible to configure Varnish to cache the API calls? POST/GET either way I don't mind.

Comment: The requests are not cached because the response sets cookies. By default Varnish does not cache when a request has cookies or a response sets a cookie.

Comment: I see. So I have to exclude this in VCL. But how about the access token in the request sent inside the header. Will this prevent Varnish to cache as well?

Comment: Varnish by default caches only GET or HEAD requests (see "sub vcl_recv" in '/etc/varnish/default.vcl'). It builds a hash based on 'req.url' and 'req.http.host' (see 'sub vcl_hash'). This means that in the default configuration you can not send access tokens in a HTTP header and expect Varnish to cache correctly. Pass the access token as a query parameter or add the header value to the hash by using the build-in function 'hash_data'.

Comment: It's possible to cache API's with varnish. Have a look at https://teq.kefh.in/api-cache-engine-with-varnish/ It's clearly explained there.